# How does this operator square to the identity matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

I know that an operator in Hilbert space applied to bra's and ket's is analogous to applying a matrix to a vector. However say if we had a random operator $\hat K=|0\rangle\langle0| - |1\rangle\langle1|$. If we square this operator it should produce a 2x2 identity matrix however I'm unsure how this comes about as I just get it equal to the same operator. I understand that the identity matrix is analogous to 1 for matrices applied to vectors however how would I determine it to be a 2x2 identity matrix? Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: The fact you got $1$ suggests you did something wrong - you should be getting an operator not a number. Could you outline your calculation?

Comment: yeh sorry I just went through it again and it produces the same operator  |0⟩⟨0|−|1⟩⟨1| not sure how I managed to get one.

Comment: |0⟩⟨0||0⟩⟨0|−|1⟩⟨1|1⟩⟨1| = |0⟩⟨0|−|1⟩⟨1| is my calculation

Comment: I must of gone wrong somewhere

Comment: Did you F.O.I.L.? That is, you must use the distributive property.

Comment: $(a-b)^2=a^2-ab-ba+b^2\neq a^2-b^2$

Comment: not sure what that method is, i'm pretty new to dirac notation so still learning the basics

Comment: I think I may be applying the operator wrong as i'm not getting the identity matrix, is there a specific method to produce the identity matrix from an operator squared? thanks!

Comment: thank you everyone for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\hat{K}^2 \equiv \hat{K}\, \hat{K} &= \left(|0\rangle \langle 0| - |1 \rangle \langle 1|\right) \left(|0\rangle \langle 0| - |1 \rangle \langle 1|\right)\\
 &= |0\rangle \langle 0|0\rangle \langle 0| +|1\rangle \langle 1|1\rangle \langle 1| - |0\rangle\langle 0 |1\rangle \langle 1| -  |1\rangle\langle 1 |0\rangle \langle 0|  \quad .
\end{align}

If we assume that $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ is an orthonormalized basis, i.e. that $\langle 0|0\rangle = \langle 1| 1\rangle= 1$ and $\langle 0|1\rangle = \langle 1|0\rangle =0$, then we obtain
$$ \hat{K}^2 = |0\rangle \langle 0| + |1\rangle \langle 1| \quad . $$

Next, consider an arbitrary vector $|\psi\rangle$ of the underlying vector space. We can expand this vector in terms of the basis vectors:
$$|\psi\rangle = c_0 |0\rangle + c_1 |1 \rangle \quad , $$
for some complex numbers $c_0, c_1 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now we have that $\mathbb{I} |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$, where $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the identity operator. As an exercise, you can apply $\hat{K}^2$ to $|\psi\rangle$ and you will see that $$\hat{K}^2 |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle \quad .$$

In other words, $\hat{K}^2$ acts as the identity operator. Since operators are defined by their action on elements of the vector space, we can conclude (since $|\psi\rangle$ was arbitrary) that
$$ \hat{K}^2 = \mathbb{I}  \quad .$$

As a side note, it is quite useful to know that there is the completeness relation:
$$ \mathbb{I} = \sum\limits_{i} |i\rangle \langle i|  \quad ,$$

for a complete basis $\{|i\rangle\}_i$.

Comment: excellent, that makes a lot of sense I knew I was missing a step in my calculation. Thank you very much Jakob!

Comment: @DiracDeltaYeah No problem. Btw: In general, if you think that an answer is particularly useful and answered your question, then you can acknowledge that by clicking the check mark beside that answer. In this way, the question will be in the category 'answered'.

Comment: Ah okay, I will bear this in mind I tried to upvote but because its my first time here it wouldn't let me, thanks again

Comment: @DiracDeltaYeah Yes, you have to earn some reputation before you're allowed to upvote answers and questions. Note that you can upvote as many answers of your question as you want, but you can only accept one answer (i.e. only use the check mark for one answer).

Comment: +1 for showing how to check the result!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it a little clearer what’s happening here, let’s write an arbitrary state
$
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<{#1}\right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left<{#1}\middle|{#2}\right>}
%
\ket{\psi} = \alpha\ket0 + \beta\ket1
$
as the column vector ${\alpha\choose\beta}$.
Then we have

\begin{align}
\hat K \ket\psi
&= \big( \ket0\bra0 - \ket1\bra1
\big) \big( \alpha\ket0 + \beta\ket1
\big)
\\ &= \alpha\ket0 - \beta\ket1
\\ \text{or}\qquad
\hat K {\alpha\choose\beta} &= {\alpha\choose-\beta}
\end{align}

This implies the matrix representation

$$
\hat K = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

which makes it a little easier to see that $\hat K{}^2$ is the identity operator.

Comment: thanks you very much!